# Quart error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'Headers' from 'h11._headers'"

Tags: python, quart

I want to start a dashboard for my nextcord bot.

But when I imported my dashboard module with the line

```
import quart
```

it raises an error.

I did not find any other posts about this.

*Error/Traceback*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1134, in <module>
    import dashboard
  File "/home/runner/tinoy/dashboard.py", line 7, in <module>
    import quart
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/quart/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .app import Quart
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/quart/app.py", line 38, in <module>
    from hypercorn.asyncio import serve
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hypercorn/asyncio/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .run import worker_serve
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hypercorn/asyncio/run.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .tcp_server import TCPServer
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hypercorn/asyncio/tcp_server.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ..protocol import ProtocolWrapper
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hypercorn/protocol/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .h2 import H2Protocol
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hypercorn/protocol/h2.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .ws_stream import WSStream
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hypercorn/protocol/ws_stream.py", line 9, in <module>
    from wsproto.connection import Connection, ConnectionState, ConnectionType
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wsproto/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .connection import Connection, ConnectionState, ConnectionType
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wsproto/connection.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .utilities import LocalProtocolError
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wsproto/utilities.py", line 12, in <module>
    from h11._headers import Headers as H11Headers
ImportError: cannot import name 'Headers' from 'h11._headers' (/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h11/_headers.py)
```

*main.py*

```py
#. . .

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.version = "0.1.1"
    bot.ipc.start()
    dashboard.run(bot)
    bot.run(Token,reconnect=True)
```

*dashboard.py*

```py
import os
import nextcord
import dotenv
import logging
import json
from func import readjson
import quart
from quart import redirect,url_for,render_template,request
from multiprocessing import Process
from quart_discord import DiscordOAuth2Session,Unauthorized,requires_authorization
from nextcord.ext import ipc
import asyncio
from threading import Thread
import aiosqlite


dotenv.load_dotenv()

ipc_client = bot.ipc_client
app = quart.Quart(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.getenv("quart_secret")
os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "true"

app.config["DISCORD_CLIENT_ID"] = os.getenv("client_id")
app.config["DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET"] = os.getenv("client_secret")
app.config["DISCORD_REDIRECT_URI"] =os.getenv("redirect_url")
app.config["DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN"] = os.getenv("Token")

discord = DiscordOAuth2Session(app)

#. . .
#Some routes…


def run(bot):
    bot.loop.create_task(app.run_task(host="0.0.0.0",port=8080))
```

I’m running on

- Python **3.8.12**
- quart **0.17.0**
- quart-discord-any **2.2.1b3**
- nextcord **2.0.0a10**

Does anyone how to solve this?

Comment: How did you install Quart? It looks like the package h11 was not installed with it, which should happen automatically.

Comment: i use `poetry install quart`

Comment: Thanks. Do you also run it with poetry, `poetry run python main.py`?

Comment: No,i don’t. i only use "python3 main.py"

Comment: Ah, that would be why then. You need to run the code in the environment Poetry has created as this includes the h11 package. If `poetry run python main.py` doesn't work please say.

Comment: It’s doesn’t work yet :(

Comment: What is the new error?

Comment: just the old error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved it by deleting the `h11` and `h11-0.13.0.dist-info` folders in my Python environment (for you this seems like the directory is `/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`) and just running `pip install quart` again afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by reinstalling h11.

The latest version h11-0.13.0 solved the problem.